# How to store the variable value after Emacs was closed

Tags: variables, persistence

Suppose, we have a variable defined in `~/.emacs`:

```
(defvar *my-var* "")
```

Then in `**scratch**` buffer we set some value to it:

```
(setq *my-var* "value")
```

After we close emacs the value will be lost. How can we store the value to disk and read it again when Emacs is started?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just add that line to the .emacs file?

Comment: @user2699 In reality I don't know the value, that will be set to `*my-var*`

Comment: This is the approach I use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321904/elisp-how-to-save-data-in-a-file

Answer (score 5):

`desktop-save-mode` will do this for you. It saves more than just the state of variables though, it also saves open buffers, window layouts and more.

To explicitly save the value of a global variable with you desktop, add the symbol to the list: `desktop-globals-to-save`. For local variables, use `desktop-locals-to-save`.

You can read more about `desktop-save-mode` [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) to learn about enabling and customizing it.

---

Alternatively, persisting your scratch buffer between sessions so you could reevaluate customizations may suffice for your example. [persistent-scratch](https://github.com/Fanael/persistent-scratch) is available on MELPA and simplifies the process of saving your scratch buffer between sessions.

Comment: Is it possible to save without a mode? Like write the variable into file?